# System.Diagnostics.Trace in WCF service implementation hosted on IIS will not work

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I want to rant and rave, really, really bad because this just seems completely unbelievable.  Instead, I'm going to try and describe my situation as clearly as possible and hope that someone will tap me on the shoulder and point out my obvious error and let me carry on merrily.

I have a client/server application where the server is a set of IIS hosted WCF services.  Thus, there are contracts and I've got service code which implements them.  When I publish  Now, I'm having a problem with a duplex contract over a nettcp binding which does not stay alive after the first response even though the client channel is cached on the server for later use in a static list, is never closed, has timeouts set appropriately, etc but the bugger doesn't want to work.

So I figured I'd add some traces to write out some extra information about where in my service implementation code it could be having a problem.  This is in addition to the System.ServiceModel trace source I have set up which logs all of the service model stuff and thankfully has been working without a problem for a while now.  Below are two different versions of the relevant section of my web.config which I have tried in an attempt to get regular tracing to write to a file:

1:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
 <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
</trace>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" propagateActivity="true">
    <!--use switchValue="All" or "Verbose" for more information-->
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
  <listeners>
    <add name="xml"/>
  </listeners>
</source>
  <source name="DuplexSource" switchValue="All" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="txt" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <remove name="Default" />
  <add name="txt" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Logs\XXXErrorLog.txt" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" />        
  <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Logs\ServerTraces.svclog" />          
</sharedListeners>
```

When I have it set thusly, I create a TraceSource object in my service code, `TraceSource duplexSource = new TraceSource("DuplexSource");`, then I use that trace source to write out statements.  The file is never created, it is never attempted to be created (using Process Monitor I can see that it never attempts).  The file permissions are wide open and the other log file for the xml listener works wonderfully.

2, I've also tried a more straight forward Trace configuration:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
     <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" propagateActivity="true">
        <!--use switchValue="All" or "Verbose" for more information-->
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="xml"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <sharedListeners>
      <remove name="Default" />
      <add name="txt" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Logs\XXXErrorLog.txt" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" />        
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Logs\ServerTraces.svclog" />          
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Again, the log file is never even attempted to be created.  Now, I've checked at runtime that I can write a file to that directory by actually doing so, then I wrote to that test file the contents of the Trace.Listeners collection to verify my listener was there, which it is.  I even then called directy into the Listener's write method and this actually does get the file to be created and the `WriteLine` call successfully writes to the file as expected.  Using `System.Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLine` does nothing however.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?